# How to Serialize ManyToMany and ForeignKey Relationship Using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a model (model.py) that return the below results (result1) in the django shell, based on the query below (query1), and it works fine.  My objective is to return the same queryset using Django Rest API, but I don't know how to manipulate my serialize to classes to to make this happen. I'm stuck on being able to return the respective user, in this case rhunter, for each task. Based on my view class below (view1.py) and my current serialized class below (serialize.py), I've been able to return the following below reults so far (result2), but I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

model.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name



@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Space(models.Model):
    space_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.space_name)

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Room(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rmfloor_name = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    sqfootage = models.IntegerField()
    spacetype = models.ForeignKey(Space, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    barcode_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Schedule(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    schedule_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schedule_name
```

query1

```
s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=1)
r1 = Room.objects.get(pk=2)
sp1 = r1.spacetype.pk
s = Space.objects.get(pk = sp1)
task_queryset = s.task.all()
for tq in task_queryset:
    print tq.pk, tq.task_name, x.schedule.user.username
```

result1

```
1   Remove large debris from floor        rhunter
2   Clean walls and horizontal surfaces   rhunter
3   Clean touch points                    rhunter
4   Empty trash container                 rhunter
6   Spot clean desks/furniture            rhunter
7   High/Low dust                         rhunter
```

view1.py

```
class TaskListMixin(object):
   s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=1)
   r1 = Room.objects.get(pk=2)
   sp1 = r1.spacetype.pk
   s = Space.objects.get(pk = sp1)
   queryset = s.task.all()
   serializer_class = SimpleSerializer3
   permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

class TaskListViewSet(TaskListMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):
   pass
```

serialize.py

```
class SimpleSerializer3(BulkSerializerMixin, ModelSerializer):



class Meta(object):
    model = Task
    list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
    fields = ('pk', 'task_name')
```

results2

```
[
{
    "pk": 1,
    "task_name": "Remove large debris from floor"
},
{
    "pk": 2,
    "task_name": "Clean walls and horizontal surfaces"
},
{
    "pk": 3,
    "task_name": "Clean touch points"
},
{
    "pk": 4,
    "task_name": "Empty trash container"
},
{
    "pk": 6,
    "task_name": "Spot clean desks/furniture"
},
{
    "pk": 7,
    "task_name": "High/Low dust"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve your problem is reading the official documentation:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

But I will give you an example based on your code.
If I were you, I would review the logic of my code to achieve what I want...

> My model.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Schedule(models.Model): 
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    schedule_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL 
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schedule_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Space(models.Model):
    space_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
    # Look at this new field...
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.space_name)

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Room(models.Model): 
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rmfloor_name = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    sqfootage = models.IntegerField()
    spacetype = models.ForeignKey(Space, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    barcode_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name
```

> My view.py

```
class SpaceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SpaceSerializer
    queryset = Space.objects.all()
```

> My serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username'
        ) 

class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = (
            'id', 'schedule_name', 'user'
        ) 


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'id', 'task_name'
        )


class SpaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = TaskSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    schedule = ScheduleSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Space
        fields = (
            'id', 'space_name', 'task', 'schedule'
        )
```

And Finally my result should be something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "space_name": "Hello World",
    "task": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "task_name": "Hello"
        }
    ],
    "schedule": {
        "id": 1,
        "schedule_name": "my schedule name",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "admin"
        }
    }
},
```

If this example does not conform to what you want, let it go and keep looking...